# "module is not installed" error with subdirs

Tags: qt, qml, subdirectory, qmake

I am working on a large Qt Application. It consists of an `App.pro` file, which defines some subdirs.

In one of the subdirs, I declare a QML module with some `qmldir` files.

I want to use `Module1` in my UI. I also created a `Module1_include.pri` which I include in my `UI.pro`.

In there I defined the `LIBTARGET`, `INCLUDEPATH`, `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` and `LIBS`.

The structure is like this, because the imported modules are from another application that I have to use because I need to support some old technologies.

I also cannot change anything in these modules. I only have control over the `.pro` and `.pri` files of `Module1`.

Structure:

- `/App.pro`
- `/imports/Module1/Module1.pro`
- `/imports/Module1/Themes/qmldir`
- `/imports/Module1/Core/qmldir`
- `/UI/UI.pro`
- `/...some more modules`

I tried set the below variables in the `.pro` file but they did not help:

- `QML_IMPORT_PATH`
- `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`